# Issue displaying data in dojo DGRID on html page

Tags: jsp, dojo, grid, dgrid

Im having an issue displaying rows of data in a dojo DGrid on a web page. I have tried OnDemandGrid and also dgrid/grid.

The issue is that I create the grid, initialize it with some json data then add it to a `div` on the html page. However it only renders an empty grid on the web page. However if I press F12 (on IE) or open debugging tools on other browsers then it will display the grid correctly complete with the data. Its like when I press F12 it triggers a repaint of the page.

Has anyone seen an issue like this?I have removed all console.log statment in case that was causing an issue but it didnt solve it.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
try {

require([ "dojo/request", "dojo/store/Memory","dgrid/OnDemandGrid" ], function(request, Memory,
                        OnDemandGrid) {
                 var testdata = [
                                 { id:1, alertCode: "Bob", alertDescription: "Barker", alertCount: 89 },
                                 { id:2, alertCode: "Vanna", alertDescription: "White", alertCount: 55 },
                                 { id:3, alertCode: "Pat", alertDescription: "Sajak", alertCount: 65 }



 var gridStore = new Memory({ data: testdata });


                store.idProperty = "id";//params.idProperty;
                style="width: 900px; height: 300px;";

                grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                    store : gridStore,
                    columns : {
                        alertCode : "Alert Code",
                        alertDescription : "Description",
                        alertCount : "Count"
                    }
                }, params.gridId);

                grid.startup();

            }); //end  grid             

            if (containerDOM !== null) {
                containerDOM.appendChild(grid.domNode);
            }

             }
             catch(e){
                 console.log("exception with grid:" + e);
             }
```

Comment: Try to append the grid to 'containerDOM' and then call grid.startup().

Comment: That worked :-) - Thank you very much - appreciate it.